# Android-studio can't install system image in arch Linux

Tags: android, archlinux

Android-studio 3.2 can't install system image in my Arch Linux gnome desktop. I tried multiple times to download Android pie system image, it can only download the image but doesn't show that to start a virtual device.

How we can solve the mentioned issue?